# ¿Como puedo añadir e eliminar elemento de una lista con posición aleatoria en python?

Tags: python, lista

El ejercicio que me mandaron trata sobre el cajero de un banco que necesita aligerar el servicio de atención a clientes (sacar tiempo total y promedio), las personas tomaran su tiempo necesario(numero aleatorio 1 al 10) y si hay una persona mayor de edad (>= 65) pasarlo de primero..
Ya logre hacer el tiempo de cada persona pero no logro posicionar a las personas mayores de 65 sin que se dupliquen

Codigo:

```
import random

#Edad de las personas en la cola
#ejemplo de la cola:
edad = [20, 18 , 65, 85, 37, 55]

tiempoCola = []

#asignar el tiempo de cada persona
while len(tiempoCola) < len(edad):
    tiempoCola.append(random.randint(1, 10))

#Sumar el tiempo total e sacar el tiempo promedio
sumaTiempo = sum(tiempoCola)
tiempoEstimado = sumaTiempo / len(tiempoCola)

print("Suma del tiempo total: {} ".format(sumaTiempo))
print("Tiempo estimado : {0:.2f}".format(tiempoEstimado))

#Edad mas alta
max_item= max(edad)
impri = "Edad mas alta: {}"
print(impri.format(max_item))

#Obtener la posicion de las personas mayores de 65
posiEdad =[i for i,x in enumerate(edad) if x >= 65]

#y colocarlo de primero (Donde todavia me complico)
num = 0
while num < len(posiEdad):
    edad.insert(0, edad[posiEdad[num]])
    num += 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asumo por el uso de `list.insert(0, ...)` que quieres que el primero en tu cola sea el item con índice 0.

Bién, primero, se duplican porque no eliminas el item en su posición inicial en la lista, solo agregas. No obstante, agregar un elemento al inicio de la misma invalida automáticamente los índices de `posiEdad`.

Además, aunque corrijas lo anterior esto cambia el orden de las personas mayores de 65 años, es decir en tu caso el de 85 pasa a estar por delante del de 65 aunque llegó después a la cola:

```
[85, 65, 20, 18, 37, 55]
```

no parece muy justo...

Por otro lado, usas ciclos `while` para iterar sobre listas sabiendo de antemano el número de iteraciones, aparte de ser menos legible y pitónico, es menos eficiente. Usa siempre ciclos `for` en estos casos, si solo quieres obtener los items de una lista usa `for item in lista:` o si necesitas indizar si o si usa `for + range`.

Si quieres, el reordenamiento de la lista lo puedes hacer en una única iteración in-place de forma muy simple, basta con llevar la cuenta de las personas movidas al inicio para ajustar el índice de inserción en `list.insert`:

```
import random

# Edad de las personas en la cola
# ejemplo de la cola:
cola = [20, 18 , 65, 85, 37, 55]

# Asignar el tiempo de cada persona
tiempo_cola = [random.randint(1, 10) for _ in range(len(cola))]

#Sumar el tiempo total e sacar el tiempo promedio
tiempo_total = sum(tiempo_cola)
tiempo_promedio = tiempo_total / len(tiempo_cola)

print(f"Suma del tiempo total: {tiempo_total}")
print(f"Tiempo estimado : {tiempo_promedio:.2f}")

# Edad mas alta
max_item = max(cola)
print(f"Edad mas alta: {max_item}")

reordenados = 0
for indice, edad in enumerate(cola):
    if edad >= 65:
        del cola[indice]
        cola.insert(reordenados, edad)
        reordenados += 1

print(f"Cola ordenada:\n{cola}")
```

> ```
> Suma del tiempo total: 40
> Tiempo estimado : 6.67
> Edad mas alta: 85
> Cola ordenada:
> [65, 85, 20, 18, 37, 55]
> ```

Si necesitas la lista de tiempos en un futuro, puedes ordenarla de acuerdo a las edades en el mismo ciclo:

```
print(f"\nCola incial:\n{cola}")
print(f"Tiempos iniciales:\n{tiempo_cola}")
​
reordenados = 0
for indice, (edad, tiempo) in enumerate(zip(cola, tiempo_cola)):
    if edad >= 65:
        del cola[indice]
        cola.insert(reordenados, edad)
        del tiempo_cola[indice]
        tiempo_cola.insert(reordenados, tiempo)
        reordenados += 1

print(f"\nCola ordenada:\n{cola}")
print(f"Tiempos ordenados:\n{tiempo_cola}")
​
```

> ```
> Suma del tiempo total: 30
> Tiempo estimado : 5.00
> Edad mas alta: 85
>
> Cola incial:
> [20, 18, 65, 85, 37, 55]
> Tiempos iniciales:
> [4, 5, 2, 10, 4, 5]
>
> Cola ordenada:
> [65, 85, 20, 18, 37, 55]
> Tiempos ordenados:
> [2, 10, 4, 5, 4, 5]
> ```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la solución y la sugerencias sobre el código para serlo mas legible